# Как удалить елементы списка b из списка a. Python

Tags: python, list

```
a = [5, 6, 7, 8]
b = [5, 8, 9]
```

Comment: вы хоть пытались найти ответ на свой вопрос? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434599/remove-list-from-list-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [5, 6, 7, 8]
b = [5, 8, 9]

for i in b:
    try:
        a.remove(i)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
a = list(filter(lambda x: x not in b, a))
```

Answer (score 2):

Или совсем элементарно:

```
a = [5, 6, 7, 8]
b = [5, 8, 9]  

a=list(set(a).difference(set(b)))

print(a)
```

Результат:

```
[6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [item for item in a if not item in b]
```